# Create input like datepicker to modal

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

i want create input like this, but not date..

"Datepicker"

[image]

number date in datepicker, change to symbol like character map..

any body help?

Answer (score 1):

I did't find something exactly for characters. but this jQuery plugin can help you to get what you want :

> [jQuery fontIconPicker](https://github.com/micc83/fontIconPicker)

you can change arrays to modify this plugin and do what you want. I hope this was helpful.